# Font face doesn't load all fonts

Tags: css, sass, fonts, font-face

I have a CSS problem with @font-face.
Here is my script :

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Atlas Grotesk';
    src: url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Thin.eot');
    src: url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Thin.woff2') format('woff2'), 
    url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Thin.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Thin.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Thin.svg#AtlasGrotesk-Thin') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Atlas Grotesk';
    src: url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Bold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Bold.svg#AtlasGrotesk-Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Atlas Grotesk';
    src: url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Regular.eot');
    src: url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Regular.svg#AtlasGrotesk-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

my problem is, that when I look to my network debugger, it just loads the regular font. So, I can't use thin or bold fonts.

environment: gulp.js, sass.

Do you have an idea?

thank you so much for your help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nv4N.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you calling the font elsewhere in your CSS? Your `@font-face` rules look correct. The browser will only download the font files it needs after parsing the CSS. If you were to use the following style rules, all the font weights would be downloaded:

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Atlas Grotesk';
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Atlas Grotesk';
  font-weight: normal;
}

.heading {
  font-family: 'Atlas Grotesk';
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

It sounds like you might have set a global font weight, such as `100`, that is preventing the other font weights from being set. Additional context might be helpful in this instance.

Comment: Thank you so much, thanks to your answer, I stopped thinking about why there's only one font that was load. Ther was a CSS rule foreward in the code that overided my font-family rule, and the font was never downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

The names are the same, that's the problem. Do something like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Atlas-Grotesk-Thin';
    src: url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Thin.eot');
    src: url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Thin.woff2') format('woff2'), 
    url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Thin.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Thin.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Thin.svg#AtlasGrotesk-Thin') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Atlas-Grotesk-Bold';
    src: url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Bold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Bold.svg#AtlasGrotesk-Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Atlas-Grotesk-Regular';
    src: url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Regular.eot');
    src: url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/hinted-AtlasGrotesk-Regular.svg#AtlasGrotesk-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

yes, u code is correct, but, u should confirm ur font-family(Rubik) is used on the page. (if ur font-family isn't used on the page, the browser will not load them)